# Airflow authentication with RBAC and Key cloak

Tags: authentication, airflow, keycloak, rbac

I want to implement rbac based auth in airflow with keycloak. Can someone help me with it.
I have creaed the webserver.config file and I am using docker to up the airflow webserver.

```
 from airflow.www_rbac.security import AirflowSecurityManager
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
    import os
    import json
    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
    
    
    
    AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
           'name': 'keycloak',
           'icon': 'fa-user-circle',
           'token_key': 'access_token',
           'remote_app': {
                'base_url': 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/',
                'request_token_params': {
                  'scope': 'email profile'
                },
                'request_token_url': None,
                'access_token_url': 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/token',
                'authorize_url': 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
                'consumer_secret': "98ec2e89-9902-4577-af8c-f607e34aa659"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I have also set the ariflow.cfg

rbac = True
authenticate = True

But still its not redirecting to the keycloak when the airflow is loaded.

I use :

```
 docker build --rm --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS="datadog,dask" --build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="flask_oauthlib>=0.9" -t airflow .
```

and

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 airflow webserver

TO execute it.

Comment: `base_url` is usually only `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/airflow`.  And are you sure about `token_key: 'access_token'`?

Comment: I had tried with out it. Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I maybe coming late to this one and my answer may not work exactly as I'm using a different auth provider, however it's still OAuth2 and in a previous life I used Keycloak so my solution should also work there.

My answer makes use of authlib (At time of writing newer versions of airflow have switched. I am on 2.1.2)

I've raised a [feature request](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1680) against Flask-AppBuilder which Airflow uses as it's OAuth hander should really take care of things when the scope includes `openid` (you'd need to add this to your scopes)

From memory keycloak returns `id_token` along side the `access_token` and `refresh_token` and so this code simply decodes what has already been returned.

```
import os
import logging
import re
import base64
import yaml
from flask import session
from airflow.www.security import AirflowSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MY_PROVIDER = 'keycloak'

class customSecurityiManager(AirflowSecurityManager):
  def oauth_user_info(self, provider, resp):
    if provider == MY_PROVIDER:
      log.debug("{0} response received : {1}".format(provider,resp))
      id_token = resp["id_token"]
      log.debug(str(id_token))
      me = self._azure_jwt_token_parse(id_token)
      log.debug("Parse JWT token : {0}".format(me))

      if not me.get("name"):
        firstName = ""
        lastName  = ""
      else:
        firstName = me.get("name").split(' ')[0]
        lastName  = me.get("name").split(' ')[-1]
      return {
        "username":   me.get("email"),
        "email":      me.get("email"),
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name":  lastName,
        "role_keys":  me.get("groups", ['Guest'])
      }
    else:
      return {}

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Guest"
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True
CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "Airflow_Users": ["User"],
    "Airflow_Admins": ["Admin"],
}

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
  {
    'name': MY_PROVIDER,
    'icon': 'fa-circle-o',
    'token_key': 'access_token',
    'remote_app': {
      'server_metadata_url':  WELL_KNOWN_URL,
      'client_id':            CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret':        CLIENT_SECRET,
      'client_kwargs': {
        'scope': 'openid groups',
        'token_endpoint_auth_method': 'client_secret_post'
      },
      'access_token_method': 'POST',
    }
  }
]
SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = customSecurityManager
```

Ironically the Azure provider already returns `id_token` and it's handled so my code makes use of that existing parsing

The code decodes `id_token`
Note you can turn on debug logging with the environmental variable `AIRFLOW__LOGGING__FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL` set to `DEBUG`.

If you switch on debug logs and see an entry like the following (note the `id_token`) you can probably use the code I've supplied.

```
DEBUG - OAUTH Authorized resp: {'access_token': '<redacted>', 'expires_in': 3600, 'id_token': '<redacted>', 'refresh_token': '<redacted>, 'scope': 'openid groups', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_at': <redacted - unix timestamp>}
```

The `id_token` is in 3 parts joined by a full stop `.` The middle part contains the user data and is simply base64 encoded

Comment: Not sure if this goes here, but your reply helped me getting FAB running with Authentik...now to figure how to manage roles. 
Thanks!