# Airflow and Keycloak integration

Tags: airflow, keycloak

I am struggling with Airflow+Keycloak integration. I installed them on k8s using helm charts: airflow-1.9.0 (app version 2.5.3) and keycloak-15.1.3 (app version 21.1.1)

The problem I am facing is: regardless of configuration used, airflow is not asking keycloak for authentication, but is using own, build-in authentication. There are no errors in logs despite using DEBUG log level.

I tried different code snippets, like this: [Airflow authentication with RBAC and Key cloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481704/airflow-authentication-with-rbac-and-key-cloak) but without a success

Below is my configmap containing airflow.cfg and airflow_local_settings.py. I would appriciate  any suggestions

```
k get configmaps airflow-airflow-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  airflow.cfg: |-
    [celery]
    flower_url_prefix = /
    worker_concurrency = 16

    [celery_kubernetes_executor]
    kubernetes_queue = kubernetes

    [core]
    colored_console_log = False
    dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags
    executor = CeleryExecutor
    load_examples = False
    remote_logging = False

    [elasticsearch]
    json_format = True
    log_id_template = {dag_id}_{task_id}_{execution_date}_{try_number}

    [elasticsearch_configs]
    max_retries = 3
    retry_timeout = True
    timeout = 30

    [kerberos]
    ccache = /var/kerberos-ccache/cache
    keytab = /etc/airflow.keytab
    principal = airflow@FOO.COM
    reinit_frequency = 3600

    [kubernetes]
    airflow_configmap = airflow-airflow-config
    airflow_local_settings_configmap = airflow-airflow-config
    multi_namespace_mode = False
    namespace = airflow
    pod_template_file = /opt/airflow/pod_templates/pod_template_file.yaml
    worker_container_repository = apache/airflow
    worker_container_tag = 2.5.3

    [kubernetes_executor]
    multi_namespace_mode = False
    namespace = airflow
    pod_template_file = /opt/airflow/pod_templates/pod_template_file.yaml
    worker_container_repository = apache/airflow
    worker_container_tag = 2.5.3

    [logging]
    colored_console_log = False
    remote_logging = False
    logging_level = DEBUG
    fab_logging_level = DEBUG

    [metrics]
    statsd_host = airflow-statsd
    statsd_on = True
    statsd_port = 9125
    statsd_prefix = airflow

    [scheduler]
    run_duration = 41460
    standalone_dag_processor = False
    statsd_host = airflow-statsd
    statsd_on = True
    statsd_port = 9125
    statsd_prefix = airflow

    [webserver]
    enable_proxy_fix = True
    rbac = True
    authenticate = True
  airflow_local_settings.py: |2-

    import os
    import logging
    import re
    import base64
    import yaml
    from flask import session
    from airflow.www.security import AirflowSecurityManager
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    MY_PROVIDER = 'keycloak'
    LOGGING_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

    class CustomSecurityManager(AirflowSecurityManager):
      def oauth_user_info(self, provider, resp):
        if provider == MY_PROVIDER:
          log.debug("{0} response received : {1}".format(provider,resp))
          id_token = resp["id_token"]
          log.debug(str(id_token))
          me = self._azure_jwt_token_parse(id_token)
          log.debug("Parse JWT token : {0}".format(me))

          if not me.get("name"):
            firstName = ""
            lastName  = ""
          else:
            firstName = me.get("name").split(' ')[0]
            lastName  = me.get("name").split(' ')[-1]
          return {
            "username":   me.get("email"),
            "email":      me.get("email"),
            "first_name": firstName,
            "last_name":  lastName,
            "role_keys":  me.get("groups", ['Guest'])
          }
        else:
          return {}

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
    AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
    AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Guest"
    AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True
    CSRF_ENABLED = True

    AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
        "Airflow_Users": ["User"],
        "Airflow_Admins": ["Admin"],
    }

    PROVIDER_NAME = 'keycloak'
    CLIENT_ID = 'airflow'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'redacted'
    OIDC_ISSUER = 'redacted'
    OIDC_BASE_URL = "{oidc_issuer}/protocol/openid-connect".format(oidc_issuer=OIDC_ISSUER)
    OIDC_TOKEN_URL = "{oidc_base_url}/token".format(oidc_base_url=OIDC_BASE_URL)
    OIDC_AUTH_URL = "{oidc_base_url}/auth".format(oidc_base_url=OIDC_BASE_URL)

    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
      'name': PROVIDER_NAME,
      'token_key': 'access_token',
      'icon': 'fa-circle-o',
      'remote_app': {
        'api_base_url': OIDC_BASE_URL,
        'access_token_url': OIDC_TOKEN_URL,
        'authorize_url': OIDC_AUTH_URL,
        'request_token_url': None,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
          'client_kwargs': {
            'scope': 'openid groups',
            'token_endpoint_auth_method': 'client_secret_post'
          },
          'access_token_method': 'POST',
        }
      }
    ]
    SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = CustomSecurityManager


    from airflow.www.utils import UIAlert

    DASHBOARD_UIALERTS = [
      UIAlert(
        'Usage of a dynamic webserver secret key detected. We recommend a static webserver secret key instead.'
        ' See the <a href='
        '"https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#webserver-secret-key">'
        'Helm Chart Production Guide</a> for more details.',
        category="warning",
        roles=["Admin"],
        html=True,
      )
    ]
```

Comment: Where you able to achieve this? If not tell me what's your existing current challenge let me see if i can help you.